# How can one get page by pagename if it is a child page?

Tags: pages

What I want to do is to dislay a description of a country if one of the categories is a country name.

It do it like that

```
    <?php
if(in_category('afghanistan')) {
    $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=25"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
}

elseif(in_category('albania')) {
    $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=26"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
}

else {
    echo "Error!";
}
?>
```

I would like to replace `page_id=25` with `pagename=afghanistan`. Iif I do so it works well, but if page "afghanistan" is a child of a page "Asia" it doesn't display it anymore. If I use `page_id` it works, but `pagename` stops working as soon as I create page as a child of another page. How do I get the page by name if it has a parent? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give a page a parent, the slug of the page becomes `%parent-pagename%/%pagename%`, so you should be able to target it with `pagename=asia/afghanistan`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easy fix, but hard to find